# Ember tests actually redirecting page

Tags: testing, ember.js

I am writing ember acceptance tests, and when redirecting as in

`visit('/get-started');`

it actually visits the page in the browser, redirecting away from `/tests`.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

I am on Ember 2.11.0

Comment: It seems to me that that is the expected behavior.  Ember acceptance tests are meant to stand up your app in a live scenario with seed data and interact with it just like a user would.  `/tests` is just a namespace for testem to load your index.html.

Comment: So you're really not supposed to use /tests? I thought I remember acceptance testing years ago with Ember, and it did everything in the testing window.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Please share some code by editing the post, then notify with a follow-up comment.

Comment: My suspicion is that you have some setting in your browser to open new links in the current window/tab rather than a new tab, or your `get-started` page has a `window.top.location=<....>` line in it somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour is by design. When you `visit('/get-started');` in your acceptance test, it should navigate to the given path in the browser, and perform whatever acceptance criteria you are trying to test.

I'm not sure what your acceptance criteria is for the `/get-started` page, but if you wanted to simply test that the navigation was successful, your test might look like:

```
test('navigate to /get-started', function(assert) {
  visit('/get-started');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentPath(), 'get-started');
  });
});
```

I'm not sure how acceptance tests worked in older versions, but for the current version(2.11.0), I think it is working as intended.